# Accessing a component's state when render() is called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using a component library and I cannot figure this out. I'm new to react and javascript and need help.
There is a component in the library that renders a header panel with tabs.
Component
|_Component.Tab

The Tab component has 2 states that change its appearance when it is clicked. But the click handler and state changes have to be defined by me outside of Tab component. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me by your question that you need to use props to pass the function to change state from the Component to the Tabs. Something like this:

**Component**

```
changeState(value) {
  this.setState({ appearance: value  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Tab
        appearance={this.state.appearance}
        onChangeState={this.changeState}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Tab**

```
render() {
  console.log('Appearance: ', this.props.appearance); // Use it for whatever you need it
  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        onClick={(value) => this.props.onChangeState(value)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I can only render Tab component, I cannot change what is inside. I need to write a function that changes Tab's state outside Tab, in the component where Tab is rendered. Is that possible?

Comment: Where is the button that changes the appearance?. Inside Tab or in the parent Component? You can use componentWillReceiveProps to check inside Tab if the property has changed and then do a setState in Tab.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you want to handle a function and it’s state outside of the component when it has to be within the Tab component. But here is the solution what you actually have to do in your Tab component to handle your state

1. Bind your handler function inside a constructor like below
   Eg:

   this.handlerFunction = this.handlerFunction.bind(this)
2. Call this.handlerFunction reference in your tab onClick
   Eg:

   onClick={this.handlerFunction}
3. Set state in handlerFunction
   Eg:

   handlerFunction(event){
        this.setState({
           tabClicked: event.target.value
         })
   }

Else I guess The outside component should be a child component that you are talking about. If so pass your tab click state as props to your outside component (i.e., child component) and receive that state as props in your child component and do setState there.

If you are still unclear then
Post your component code here. With Just theory it’s little difficult to understand the actual problem that you are talking about.